# Adding a song to a playlist suddenly doesn't let me choose existing playlists. I can only add it to a new playlist

Tags: itunes, apple-music, music.app, playlist

I used to add songs to a playlist by right-clicking it and then selecting "Add to Playlist." It would show all existing playlists that are not smart. But today, somehow I can't do that anymore. It seems to have forgotten all my playlists, even though they're still there, and I can still drag the song into them as an alternative.

I updated to Sonoma 14.2.1 yesterday. And today, when I clicked on an unauthorized song in my library, I couldn't play any songs at all, and at one point the contents of all my playlists were empty. I had to restart my Mac a few times (not just force-quitting the app) to get it working somewhat normally again. But that's when I ran into this problem.

Any help to solve this issue would be much appreciated!

Comment: My experience has been that I am unable to add a song from Apple Music to a playlist of files I have on my computer.